# Update all object properties at once

Tags: json, node.js, crud

I have some complex / nested object.

```
var acctTypes = {
"prop1" : "aaaa" , 
"prop2" : "bbbb" , 
"prop3" : [
  { 
    ... ,
    "propToUpdate" : " ... " , 
    ...
  },
{ 
    ... ,
    "propToUpdate" : " ... " , 
    ...
  },
{ 
    ... ,
    "propToUpdate" : " ... " , 
    ...
  }
] , 
"prop4" : "xxxx"
}
```

I was wondering if there more elegant way to update specific property (propToUpdate) other than foreach loop.

Thanks

Comment: You need to show an example of the object and how you do it now. Otherwise this is way too vague.

Comment: Kindly Provide some code example and schema as well. Thanks.

Comment: @FarhanTahir - example was provided :)

Comment: @Igal Have a look at my answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You could do but problem is you need have embedded property as in the filter query as per mongodb

> IMPORTANT
>
> You must include the array field as part of the query document.

Though you can do something like this:

```
db.getCollection('acctTypes').update({_id: ObjectId("5ac1e018be3f841f61b4513a"), "prop3_filter_property": prop3_filter_value}, {$set: {"prop3.$.propToUpdate" : "updatedValue"}})
```

In mongoose:

```
AcctTypes.update(
        { 
          _id: id, 
          "prop3_filter_property": prop3FilterValue
        }, 
        {
          $set : {
           "prop3.$.propToUpdate": updateValue
          }
        }
      )
```